# UnicodeDecodeError in `re.Pattern.search()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.3

I've received a bug report for a library I wrote. The symptom is that the `search` method of a compiled `Pattern` is raising `UnicodeDecodeError`. The Python `re` library docs do not mention `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 32: invalid start byte
```

The argument to `search` is a Windows file path. I suspect that the path in question is ill-formed UTF-16 and that the (third-party, compiled, closed-source) code that's interacting with the filesystem is creating a malformed Python string object, and then `search` is failing in an unusual manner as a result. Unfortunately, I don't have any specific information about what the broken file path might be, so I can't test it directly.

My questions:

1. Is this a plausible thing that could happen?
2. Is there any way within pure Python to construct a malformed Python string, or to check whether a given string is malformed?

Comment: on windows the most compatible encoding is cp1252. `b"\xA1".decode("cp1252")` works

Comment: Are you really sure this happens inside `re.pattern.search`, not before? A malformed or misinterpreted path is a plausible cause, but a malformed `str` object is extremely unlikely – the error message indicates that decoding a `bytes` object to `str` already fails. Since `re.pattern.search` doesn't implicitly coerce between `str`/`bytes`, I assume this happens earlier. That being said, I'm unfamiliar with how things were back in Python 3.3; it has reached EOL quite some time ago.

Comment: As sure as I can be without being able to test it (hence the question). The line indicated in the stack trace is `return lambda s: (expr.search(s) is not None)`. Moreover, none of this code is explicitly dealing with encodings or bytes in the first place — every value is already a string by the time my library sees it. By all rights, it should be impossible to get a UnicodeDecodeError, but here we are.